# Titan server start fails

Tags: titan

I see the following message when starting titan-server:

```
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("titan" conflicts with "titan"))
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$system_add_keyspace_result.read(Cassandra.java:33158)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_system_add_keyspace(Cassandra.java:1408)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.system_add_keyspace(Cassandra.java:1395)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl$9.internalExecute(ThriftClusterImpl.java:250)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl$9.internalExecute(ThriftClusterImpl.java:247)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
... 26 more
```

Here is how i start it.

```
~/titan-server-0.4.0$ bin/titan.sh -c cassandra-es start
```

What am i missing? Thanks for any help.

Of course, After I run

```
titan.sh -c cassandra-es clean
```

and it starts up just fine. Does that mean there was something wrong with my data.

Comment: When you do `clean` you say that it "starts up just fine".  Does that mean you've only seen the problem once? Or are you able to easily get Titan Server into a scenario where you can easily recreate it?  If you can recreate it, what are the steps to do so?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I ended up doing 'clean' to see if the problem would go away and it did. I will load the graph again today and see when the problem comes back. But I was having this problem for a while and usually it would take a bounce or two for it to go away and this time it didn't.

Comment: Update: I am not seeing this issue with titan-server-0.4.1 so far. I will update this thread again if I see otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly start titan by

> bin/titan.sh start